# How to make numpy clip run faster?

Tags: python, numpy, cython, numba

I have a custom machine learning objective function which is a kind of a linear bounded function and mainly use numpy.clip. During training, the objective function will be run a whole of times. The training time thus depends on how fast numpy.clip can run.

So, my question is 'is there anything I can do to make numpy.clip run faster?'

So far, I tried numba but I basically get no improvement at all (example below).

```
import timeit
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

def clip(x, l, u):
    return x.clip(l, u)

@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True, fastmath=True)
def clip2(x, l, u):
    return x.clip(l, u)

x = np.random.rand(1000)
l = -np.random.rand(1000)
u = np.random.rand(1000)

timeit.timeit(lambda: clip(x, l, u))
>>> 7.600710524711758
timeit.timeit(lambda: clip2(x, l, u))
>>> 23.19934402871877
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I use numba or it really cannot help in this case?

Is there any other approach worth a try?

One note is for my use case, the vector length for x, l and u in clip (defined above) is mainly around 1000. So, I really want to optimize for such a particular case.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: `clip` already uses compiled code.

Comment: _`timeit.timeit("lambda: clip(x, l, u)")`_ is timing how long it takes to create a callable.  I think you want `timeit.timeit(lambda: clip(x, l, u))` or perhaps `timeit.timeit("clip(x, l, u)", globals=globals())`.

Comment: `x.clip(l, u)` will be faster and perhaps `x.clip(l, u, out=x)` may be what you are looking for.  `numba` results should be even faster.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thanks. x.clip(l, u) is a bit faster indeed. But numba in my case is significantly slower. Did I do something wrong? My example code is updated.

Comment: For `clip2` use `@jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True)` and see how fast that goes. `parallel=True` generated `numba` warnings for me.  On my machine `numba` is about 3.6 times faster than `numpy`.

Comment: What makes you think clip is the bottleneck? Did you do any profiling to confirm this?

Comment: @PaulH Yes, I did actually.

Comment: @rickhg12hs would you mind putting your example code in an answer post?

Comment: Did you run `timeit.timeit(lambda: clip2(x, l, u))` more than once?  The first measurement may be heavily biased by `numba` compile time.

Comment: Using single threaded `@njit(parallel=False)` and excluding compilation (running the function twice) `numba` is 3x faster in my benchmarks. `parallel=True` yields a warning, that *no transformation for parallel execution was possible*, did you miss the warning?

Comment: @rickhg12hs indeed, i do see faster time without parallel=True.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny parallel=True does have warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, Numba introduces some compilation overhead the first time the function is called (for a particular datatype signature). Whether that should be included in the benchmark is difficult to answer based on the limited information you've shared.

The Numpy functions supported by Numba are convenient and robust, but you can often gain a little extra performance by implementing a specific function for your application.

The `parallel=True` doesn't do anything as shown by the warning.

Using `np.clip` you could perhaps gain a little by using the `out=` keyword if you're willing to modify the input (in place).

Overall I get the best performance using `numba.vectorize`, as is often the case in my experience.

```py
from numba import njit, vectorize
import numpy as np

def clip1(x, l, u):
    return x.clip(l, u)

@njit(fastmath=True)
def clip2(x, l, u):
    return x.clip(l, u)
    
@njit(fastmath=True)
def clip3(x, l, u):
    return np.clip(x, l, u, out=x)
    
@vectorize
def clip4(x, l, u):
    return max(min(x, u), l)
```

On my machine, with a warm-up (excluding compilation), this results in:

```
clip1: 7.19 µs ± 546   ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
clip2: 2.88 µs ±  35.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
clip3: 2.54 µs ± 177   ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
clip4: 1.2  µs ±  39.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Comment: It is worth noting that `numba.vectorize` is NOT compatible with `numba.jit`. Because of this limitation, it is not possible to call vectorized method from other jitted method.

Comment: My bad, it is `numba.guvectorize` that is not compatible, not `numba.vectorize` !

Comment: @duburcqa That's probably supported soon, keep an eye on this PR if you're interested in this. https://github.com/numba/numba/pull/8984

Answer (score 0):

For the record, on my side (Apple M3) the fastest implementation is this one:

```
@nb.jit(fastmath=True)
def clip(x, l, u):
    return np.maximum(np.minimum(x, u), l)
```